# iPhone 6 Plus battery reduced to a fourth of what it was recently

Tags: iphone, battery, charging

I have an iPhone 6 Plus - Bought the Plus size because I could really do with a better battery.

The battery used to be excellent earlier - lasting upto 2 days on one full charge

The phone is barely 3 months old, but all of a sudden since last week, the battery drains real fast and the device is hot most of the time - I reset the device, turned of the Location service and the background apps and all such general things.

Here is a screenshot of a fully charged phone at 4 PM discharged to 50% at 8 PM with barely any use meanwhile.

[image]

I suspect this to be a hardware issue. Any way I can prove this? Unfortunately, here in India Apple care centres hardly help and just take away your phone for weeks, wipe it and return it as it is.

Can I request a hardware diagnostic to Apple Care on phone, that I can execute?

Answer (score 2):

iOS 9 lets you see exactly what's using battery over the past day and the past week.

- Go to Settings > Battery
- Wait for the list to populate
- Tap "Show detailed usage" to see a breakdown of foreground and background usage for each process
- Switch between "Last 24 Hours" and "Last 7 Days" to see what might have changed for you 2 days ago.

For much more on this feature, including some advice on how to make sense of the data, see http://www.imore.com/how-see-whats-using-battery-life-your-iphone-or-ipad